# Output Java DOM over HTTP

Tags: java, http, dom, servlets

Not so long ago I found a way of sending a DOM representation of an XML document out over an HTTP connection from a Servlet. AFAIK the DOM 3 LS (LoadStore) is needed for this, but the thread on StackOverflow showing how to do it seems to have disappeared.

Can anyone please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use JAXP:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(dom), new StreamResult(out));
```

You might want to use JAX RS instead (never used it):

```
@Path("/foo.xml")
public class MyResource {
  @GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Source asXml() {
     // TODO, get your DOM somehow
     return new DOMSource(dom);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure if this is an unrelated question but your solution works if I place the code in the main servlet file that eclipse put in place for me by default, but if I put the code in another file I get the following error: XML Parsing Error: no element found (not sure what causes it).

Comment: Because you have not mapped the other servlet and you are still querying on the "default" one? I have no other idea ...